# How can I check if the Cache Channel Service is running?

Tags: cache-channel-service

I want to check whether Tridion Cache Channel Service is running or not. Please let me know where we can check this.

Comment: Have you installed Tridion's monitoring services? Also, please share more about your installation. Are you on a windows platform etc?

Answer (score 8):

There's probably 2 or 3 questions hiding behind that seemingly simple question...

If you want to find it the CCS is running, the easiest is to open a telnet connection to the server and port that it's configured to run on. If you get no answer, then CCS is not running.

If you want to find out if the CCS is *working* it's a different ball game. Here you'll have to play around with logging levels until you're happy with what you see - I'd recommend reading [this excellent post](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/analyzing_object_cache.aspx) from @puf.

If you want to *monitor* the CCS status, then you're probably better off using the Monitoring Service from Tridion, or any other system that can monitor the health status of a (Java) process.